# PHP - Read three lines of remote html

Tags: php, file-get-contents, trim

I need to read three lines of a remote page using PHP. I'm using code from Jose Vega found here to read the title:

```
<?php

function get_title($url){
  $str = file_get_contents($url);
  if(strlen($str)>0){
    $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str)); // supports line breaks    inside <title>
    preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title); // ignore case
    return $title[1];
  }
}
//Example:
echo get_title("http://www.washingtontimes.com/");

?>
```

When I plug in a URL, I want to extract the following information:

```
<title>TITLE HERE</title>

<meta property="end_date" content="Tue Aug 28 2018 03:59:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)" />

<meta property="start_date" content="Mon Aug 06 2018 04:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)" />
```

Outputs: `$title`, `$start`, `$end`
Displayed as a title with a link to URL, followed by Starts: ____, Ends: ____, preferably converted to simple dates

Bonus Question: How can I efficiently parse dozens of sites using this script? The sites are all ascending numerically. `index.php?id=103 index.php?id=104 index.php?id=105`

Displaying:

```
ID   Title         Start     End

#103 TitleWithLink StartDate EndDate

#104 TitleWithLink StartDate EndDate

#105 TitleWithLink StartDate EndDate
```

Comment: This seems like pretty basic PHP. On this site you need to show the code you have tried and ask for assistance with that. Its not a free consultation site :-).  Having said that, can you provide a few example site with the <meta property="start_date" ... you will need these for testing.

Comment: Thanks @bcperth. As you can see I posted the code I was trying and wasn't getting far, so I asked for assistance from the professionals. I understand you want to avoid people coming in here asking for free coding to be done essentially. I'm just far from a php programmer. Total noob.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question i guessed you want to read metadata.A part of the code i will suggest now has been taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php
.It works fine for this SO page so it will work fine for yours too.Of course you will need to adapt it a little to get your task done.

```
function getUrlData($url, $raw=false) // $raw - enable for raw display
{
    $result = false;

    $contents = getUrlContents($url);

    if (isset($contents) && is_string($contents))
    {
        $title = null;
        $metaTags = null;
        $metaProperties = null;

        preg_match('/<title>([^>]*)<\/title>/si', $contents, $match );

        if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) > 0)
        {
            $title = strip_tags($match[1]);
        }

        preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*(name|property)="?' . '([^>"]*)"?[\s]*' . 'content="?([^>"]*)"?[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);

        if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) == 4)
        {
            $originals = $match[0];
            $names = $match[2];
            $values = $match[3];

            if (count($originals) == count($names) && count($names) == count($values))
            {
                $metaTags = array();
                $metaProperties = $metaTags;
                if ($raw) {
                    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') == -1)
                         $flags = ENT_COMPAT;
                    else
                         $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401;
                }

                for ($i=0, $limiti=count($names); $i < $limiti; $i++)
                {
                    if ($match[1][$i] == 'name')
                         $meta_type = 'metaTags';
                    else
                         $meta_type = 'metaProperties';
                    if ($raw)
                        ${$meta_type}[$names[$i]] = array (
                            'html' => htmlentities($originals[$i], $flags, 'UTF-8'),
                            'value' => $values[$i]
                        );
                    else
                        ${$meta_type}[$names[$i]] = array (
                            'html' => $originals[$i],
                            'value' => $values[$i]
                        );
                }
            }
        }

        $result = array (
            'title' => $title,
            'metaTags' => $metaTags,
            'metaProperties' => $metaProperties,
        );
    }

    return $result;
}

function getUrlContents($url, $maximumRedirections = null, $currentRedirection = 0)
{
    $result = false;

    $contents = @file_get_contents($url);

    // Check if we need to go somewhere else

    if (isset($contents) && is_string($contents))
    {
        preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*http-equiv="?REFRESH"?' . '[\s]*content="?[0-9]*;[\s]*URL[\s]*=[\s]*([^>"]*)"?' . '[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);

        if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) == 2 && count($match[1]) == 1)
        {
            if (!isset($maximumRedirections) || $currentRedirection < $maximumRedirections)
            {
                return getUrlContents($match[1][0], $maximumRedirections, ++$currentRedirection);
            }

            $result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $result = $contents;
        }
    }

    return $contents;
}

$result = getUrlData('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939042/php-read-three-lines-of-remote-html', true);
```

the output of `print_r($result);` is:

```
Array
(
    [title] => file get contents - PHP - Read three lines of remote html - Stack Overflow
    [metaTags] => Array
        (
            [viewport] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
                    [value] => width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0
                )

            [twitter:card] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
                    [value] => summary
                )

            [twitter:domain] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
                    [value] => stackoverflow.com
                )

            [twitter:app:country] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="twitter:app:country" content="US" />
                    [value] => US
                )

            [twitter:app:name:iphone] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="Stack Exchange iOS" />
                    [value] => Stack Exchange iOS
                )

            [twitter:app:id:iphone] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="871299723" />
                    [value] => 871299723
                )

            [twitter:app:url:iphone] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939042/php-read-three-lines-of-remote-html" />
                    [value] => se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939042/php-read-three-lines-of-remote-html
                )

            [twitter:app:name:ipad] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="twitter:app:name:ipad" content="Stack Exchange iOS" />
                    [value] => Stack Exchange iOS
                )

            [twitter:app:id:ipad] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="871299723" />
                    [value] => 871299723
                )

            [twitter:app:url:ipad] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939042/php-read-three-lines-of-remote-html" />
                    [value] => se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939042/php-read-three-lines-of-remote-html
                )

            [twitter:app:name:googleplay] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="twitter:app:name:googleplay" content="Stack Exchange Android">
                    [value] => Stack Exchange Android
                )

            [twitter:app:url:googleplay] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939042/php-read-three-lines-of-remote-html">
                    [value] => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939042/php-read-three-lines-of-remote-html
                )

            [twitter:app:id:googleplay] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="com.stackexchange.marvin">
                    [value] => com.stackexchange.marvin
                )

        )

    [metaProperties] => Array
        (
            [og:url] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939042/php-read-three-lines-of-remote-html"/>
                    [value] => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939042/php-read-three-lines-of-remote-html
                )

            [og:site_name] => Array
                (
                    [html] => <meta property="og:site_name" content="Stack Overflow" />
                    [value] => Stack Overflow
                )

        )

)
```

Then to actually use it to achieve your purpose:

> How can I efficiently parse dozens of sites using this script? The
>   sites are all ascending numerically. index.php?id=103 index.php?id=104
>   index.php?id=105

you need to :

1. -first create an `array` containing your urls

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
               <html>
               <head>
               </head>
               <body>

               <h2>HTML Table</h2>

               <table>
                       <tr>
                       <th >Id</th>
                       <th >Title</th>
                       <th >start_date</th>
                       <th>end_date</th>
                       </tr>
           <?php
   $urls=array(103=>'index.php?id=103',104=> 'index.php?id=104', 105=>'index.php?id=105');
   ```
2. -then loop through this `array` :

   ```
   foreach($urls as $id=>$url):
   ```
3. -each iteration you use the function `getUrlData()` as shown:

   ```
       $result=getUrlData($url, true);
   ```
4. -then you retrieve the needed information using eg:

   ```
   ?><tr>
     <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $result['title']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $result['metaProperties']['start_date']['value']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $result['metaProperties']['end_date']['value']; ?></td>
   </tr>
   ```

   to build each line and row.
   At the end of the process you would have get your expected table:

   ```
   Endforeach;?>
               </table></body>
               </html>
   ```

Comment: thank you this is a very thorough and in depth answer, but sadly I'm not getting it to display results properly. And the endforeach isn't parsing at all. It displays the ID and Title of the first item in the array but no others. And no start or end dates. Here's the live code. [link](http://www.sweepsplus.com/dj/index.php) and [link](http://www.sweepsplus.com/dj/index.txt)

Comment: you  have many errors in your codes .this is why it didn't work.it works for me

Comment: You got an error at line 96 : instead of :`foreach($urls as $id=>$url);` you muse write : `foreach($urls as $id=>$url):` .You must also write `<?php` just before the `endforeach;` at line 106;

Comment: you also need to change your code at step 4: instead of `$result['metaTags']` use `$result['metaProperties']` it works fine with these changes.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I would have never figured this out between playing with get_meta_tags lol

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could solve your issue with the DomDocument class.

```
$doc = new \DomDocument();
$title = $start = $end = '';

if ($doc->loadHTMLFile($url)) {

    // Get the title
    $titles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
    if ($titles->length > 0) {
        $title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }

    // get meta elements
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
    $ends = $xpath->query('//meta[@property="end_date"]');
    $if ($ends->length > 0) {
        $end = $ends->item(0)->getAttribute('content');
    }

    $starts = $xpath->query('//meta[@property="start_date"]');
    if ($starts->length > 0) {
        $start = $starts->item(0)->getAttribute('content');
    }

    var_dump($title, $start, $end);
}
```

With the `getElementsByTagName` method of the `DomDocument` class you can find the title element in the whole html of a given url. With the `DOMXPath` class you can retrieve the specific meta data you want. You don 't need much code for finding specific informations in a html string.

The code shown above is not tested.

Comment: This is much simpler coding. Do I call it as easily as index.php?url=www.sample.com? Or can I use an array like Elementary's answer using loadHTMLFile($url) in a loop?

Comment: You can execute this piece of code in a loop as well as using GET parameters. I would prefer the GET parameter solution by calling it as `index.php?url=www.sample.com` via CURL and returning the needed data as JSON string or something similar. The runtime and the memory usage in this case is smaller than running a loop, because you start the script with every new url GET parameter over and over again. Anyway ... you can use it both ways. Which one you decide yourself.